# 'double mixins' support in dotless

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, compiler-errors, less, dotless

It seems that the dotless compiler cannot handle the following case.
In the **bootsrap buttons.less file** I want to use the mixin:

```
// Disabled state
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled] {
  cursor: default;
  background-image: none;
  background-color: darken(@white, 10%);
  .opacity(65);
  .box-shadow(none);
}
```

I use this mixin in my less file like this:

```
@import "../buttons.less
.state2 .followButton{
                .follow{ display:block; }
                .following{ display:none; }
                .unfollow{ display:none; }
                .btn.disabled;
                pointer-events:none;
            }
```

The compiler raises the following error:

```
.btn.disabled is undefined on line 178 in file '/myFile.less':
```

With winless, the css compiles without any problem hence my idea that the compiler is the 'problem'.

Is that a known issue? (Is it an issue at all?)
What would you recommend for projects like mine which are based on bootstrap?

*As a side question, why not using the regular less compiler in dotless? Is there any technical reason?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isn't this caused by an incorrect import? Your import line should end with ";

```
@import "../buttons.less";
```

The following code produces the desired output:

```
.btn.disabled, .btn[disabled] {
  font-size: 120%;
}

.foo {
  .btn.disabled;
}
```

Produces:

```
.btn.disabled,
.btn[disabled] {
  font-size: 120%;
}
.foo {
  font-size: 120%;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was the problem.